# Query regarding the academic journal submission

Tags: mathematics, journals, paper-submission, affiliation, stem

Asking on behalf of my friend.

He had worked on some problems in the summer of 2018 when he was a student at some X university. After a year, he again started working on the same problem and will be going to publish it in some journal. But now he joined university Y.

He has this query: what author's address and mail he needs to mention on the paper? Or what else he needs to do?

PS: The funding for the summer internship was given by university X.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You want to provide maximal useful information. That should include funding sources and a current address.
Your friend should provide the journal with all that information. They will decide how to use it. A paper I wrote years ago needed three affiliations. It started with

[image]

The footnote read

[image]

That was in the days before email. Now there would be a current email address.

Comment: And a "Research funded by...." note might also be needed.

Comment: Can we provide the funding information in the acknowledgment section?

Comment: @Vans1904 You can put it there.  The editor may decide to put it elsewhere. Just be sure to include it somewhere.